# Generate interface from abstract class

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way in `eclipse` to generate (refactoring, etc.) an `interface` from an `abstract class`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In think in the context menu in java file, you have the option "refactor". I'm sure the option is there but I dont remember the exact path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a right click -> refactor -> Extract Interface -> select members to declare in interface(checkbox, it lists all the public methods there).

PS - I tried on eclipse neon.